# disable "Press ENTER or type command to continue" in terminal

Tags: vim

I know how to disable this inside Vim, I am curious is it possible to disable this at all when running vim in terminal.

e.g.

```
tdi@piesek:~$ vim
ycm_client_support.[so|pyd|dll] and ycm_core.[so|pyd|dll] not detected; you need to compile YCM before using it. Read the docs!
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

My scenario is that I install vim and Vundle plugins automatically via saltstack for all users (`vim +PluginInstall +qall`). Some plugins, however need more love, e.g. YouCompleteMe, which gives this message.

I would like to force vim to 'go on' even when there are some things that keep on wanting ENTER pressed.

Answer (score 4):

If you know the commands (in your `~/.vimrc`) who trigger the message, you can prepend `:silent!` in front of it. This will suppress any output and errors.

For general messages, you can try `:set nomore`.

Comment: I assume I do not know what causes this. That is the problem :)

Comment: @Dārayavahuštdi the `PluginInstall` command, I think. Try `vim +'silent! PluginInstall' +qall`.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe
./install.py
```

Fixed this problem for me, I have Ubuntu 14 as OS and `CMake` installed, previously..

Answer (score -2):

I tried it by deleting one by one.And I find that `set syntax` cause the problem..not sure if is the culprit.

So you can delete it to solve the problem.

Comment: If you know this will fix the problem then say so, and don't qualify it with "not sure".  If you're not sure, then this shouldn't be posted as an answer, and should instead be a comment.